# ¿Comó agregar un una array dentro de otro array con PHP 7.2.10?

Tags: php, array

Necesito guardar el array ($array_ord_det) dentro del array ($productos) he probado con el siguiente código pero no me funciona.

```
           $array_ord_det=array();
           $productos = array();
           if (isset($r_ord_cust->id)) {     
             if ((string)$r_ord_cust->id==(string)$r_ord_detail->id_order ) {
                  echo "IF: ORDERS_DETAIL"."<br>";
                  foreach ($r_ord_detail as $key => $value) {
                       if ($key=="id") {                          
                           $array_ord_det[$key] = (string)$value;                         
                       }elseif ($key=="product_quantity") {
                            $array_ord_det[$key] = (string)$value;                      
                       }elseif ($key=="product_name") {
                            $array_ord_det[$key] = (string)$value;
                       }
                  }                                                   
                  array_push($productos, array($array_ord_det));   
              }
           }
```

Tal vez alguien me puede ayudar con este problema. Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sólo tienes que agregar el array "$array_ord_det" en un índice de tu otro array "$productos". Es decir:

Con esto lo agregarás al final de tu array:

```
$productos[] = $array_ord_det;
```

Si necesitas agregarlo en una posición determinada, siendo $posición esa posición:

```
$productos[$posicion] = $array_ord_det;
```

---

UPDATE:

Disculpame, probablemente ha sido fallo mio por dar por hecho cosas:

En lugar de poner el array_push, sustituye esa linea:

```
 array_push($productos, array($array_ord_det));
```

Por la que te comentaba:

```
$productos[] = $array_ord_det;
```

Con esto, al final deberías tener algo asi:

```
$produtos = array(
                   [0] => array(
                               'id' => ...
                               'product_quantity' => ...
                               'product_name' => ...
                          )
            )
```

Comment: He probando de esa manera pero se me añade en diferentes arrays, lo que necesito es que se añadan todos en un solo array.

Answer (score 0):

```
//array_push($productos, array($array_ord_det)); 

$productos['detalles'] = $array_ord_det;
```